# samba classicupgrade from samba3 to samba4

Tags: samba, upgrade, samba4

I'm very confused with doing samba upgrade from samba 3.5 (debian squezze) to samba 4.1 (ubuntu 14.04 lts)
What i'm done now? all from official samba wiki:

[https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Migrating_a_Samba_NT4_domain_to_a_Samba_AD_domain_%28classic_upgrade%29]

My scenario is to do backup of existing samba 3 on old machine, transfer files to new machine and do classicupgrade from this file.
I can't do classicupgrade on old machine because is on production site and can't be unavailable.

Now on new machine i have working open ldap with imported database from old one, and also have files smb.conf and /var/lib/samba/* from old machine.
I have checked ldap for duplicate names of users and groups.

To do classicupgrade i run command:

```
samba-tool domain classicupgrade --dbdir=/dir/with/files/from/old/machine/var/lib/samba/ --use-xattrs=yes \ 
--realm=office.mycompany.com --dns-backend=SAMBA_INTERNAL /patch/to/samba3/smb.conf
```

and the output of this command is:

```
    eading smb.conf
    Provisioning
    Exporting account policy
    Exporting groups
    Exporting users
      Skipping wellknown rid=500 (for username=administrator)
    Next rid = 10003
    Exporting posix attributes
    Reading WINS database
    Looking up IPv4 addresses
    Looking up IPv6 addresses
    No IPv6 address will be assigned
    Setting up share.ldb
    Setting up secrets.ldb
    Setting up the registry
    Setting up the privileges database
    Setting up idmap db
    Setting up SAM db
    Setting up sam.ldb partitions and settings
    Setting up sam.ldb rootDSE
    Pre-loading the Samba 4 and AD schema
    Adding DomainDN: DC=office,DC=mycompany,DC=com
    Adding configuration container
    Setting up sam.ldb schema
    Setting up sam.ldb configuration data
    Setting up display specifiers
    Modifying display specifiers
    Adding users container
    Modifying users container
    Adding computers container
    Modifying computers container
    Setting up sam.ldb data
    Setting up well known security principals
    Setting up sam.ldb users and groups
    Setting up self join
    Setting acl on sysvol skipped
    Adding DNS accounts
    Creating CN=MicrosoftDNS,CN=System,DC=office,DC=mycompany,DC=com
    Creating DomainDnsZones and ForestDnsZones partitions
    Populating DomainDnsZones and ForestDnsZones partitions
    Setting up sam.ldb rootDSE marking as synchronized
    Fixing provision GUIDs
    A Kerberos configuration suitable for Samba 4 has been generated at /var/lib/samba/private/krb5.conf
    Setting up fake yp server settings
    Once the above files are installed, your Samba4 server will be ready to use
    Admin password:        ..........................
    Server Role:           active directory domain controller
    Hostname:              DC1
    NetBIOS Domain:        mycompany
    DNS Domain:            office.mycompany.com
    DOMAIN SID:            S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662
    Importing WINS database
    Importing Account policy
    Importing idmap database
    Adding groups
    Importing groups
    Group already exists sid=S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-513, groupname=Domain Users existing_groupname=Domain Users, Ignoring.
    Group already exists sid=S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-514, groupname=Domain Guests existing_groupname=Domain Guests, Ignoring.
    Group already exists sid=S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-515, groupname=Domain Computers existing_groupname=Domain Computers, Ignoring.
    Commiting 'add groups' transaction to disk
    Adding users
    Importing users
    Commiting 'add users' transaction to disk
    Adding users to groups
   Commiting 'add users to groups' transaction to disk
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-549: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-549: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-18: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-18: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-11: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-11: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-544: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    enum_group_memberships failed for S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-500: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    Fall back to unix uid lookup
    idmap range not specified for domain '*'
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 1 (min password length), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 2 (password history), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 3 (user must logon to change password), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 4 (maximum password age), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 5 (minimum password age), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 6 (lockout duration), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 7 (reset count minutes), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 8 (bad lockout attempt), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 9 (disconnect time), returning 0
    account_policy_get: tdb_fetch_uint32 failed for type 10 (refuse machine password change), returning 0
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-544: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    enum_group_memberships failed for S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-500: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    Fall back to unix uid lookup
    idmap range not specified for domain '*'
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-549: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-549: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-18: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-18: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-11: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-11: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-544: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    enum_group_memberships failed for S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-500: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    Fall back to unix uid lookup
    idmap range not specified for domain '*'
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
Fall back to unix uid lookup
idmap range not specified for domain '*'
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-544: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
enum_group_memberships failed for S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-500: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    Fall back to unix uid lookup
    idmap range not specified for domain '*'
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[0]=S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-512: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
    ERROR(<class 'passdb.error'>): uncaught exception - Unable to get id for sid
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 175, in _run
        return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 1318, in run
        useeadb=eadb, dns_backend=dns_backend, use_ntvfs=use_ntvfs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/upgrade.py", line 983, in upgrade_from_samba3
        result.names.domaindn, result.lp, use_ntvfs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1581, in setsysvolacl
        set_gpos_acl(sysvol, dnsdomain, domainsid, domaindn, samdb, lp, use_ntvfs, passdb=s4_passdb)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1511, in set_gpos_acl
        passdb=passdb)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1474, in set_dir_acl
        setntacl(lp, path, acl, domsid, use_ntvfs=use_ntvfs, skip_invalid_chown=True, passdb=passdb, service=service)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 104, in setntacl
        (owner_id, owner_type) = passdb.sid_to_id(sd.owner_sid)
```

After that samba-tool can list users and group but can't add computers, and command

```
samba-tool ntacl sysvolreset
```

exit with error:

```
ERROR(<class 'passdb.error'>): uncaught exception - Unable to get id for sid
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 175, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/ntacl.py", line 208, in run
    (BA_gid,BA_type) = s4_passdb.sid_to_id(BA_sid)
```

Can someone help me with understanding what i'm doing wrong or what i shut to do more ?

When i'm trying to log as someone to network share in samba4 logs i have this:

```
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[2]=S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-520: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[3]=S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-572: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[4]=S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-519: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[5]=S-1-5-21-2669135327-1831268680-3250772662-518: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[7]=S-1-1-0: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[8]=S-1-5-2: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[9]=S-1-5-11: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[10]=S-1-5-32-544: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[11]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[12]=S-1-5-32-554: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[6]=S-1-1-0: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[7]=S-1-5-2: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[8]=S-1-5-11: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[9]=S-1-5-32-545: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
idmapping sid_to_xid failed for id[10]=S-1-5-32-554: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
```

I think is something with groups mappings but don't know how to fix that.
Is there possibility to edit some samba3 or ldap files , even manually to correct this problem ?

Regards

Comment: anybody ? i think is something with gorup mappings but not understand how to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK got it, i should not copy all files from /var/lib/samba from old server but only this files:

```
# secrets.tdb
# schannel_store.tdb
# passdb.tdb
# group_mapping.tdb
# account_policy.tdb
# smb.conf
```

and use only this file for classic upgrade procedure.